# What's the purpose of subfolders inside a theme's templates folder?

Tags: 8, theming

What is the purpose of folders inside the templates folder in a theme? Where is specified that when rendering a page the template should be taken from `layout/page.html.twig`? Or a single node template from `content/node.html.twig`?

I could see content, block, field, form etc. in the `/templates` folder. I am referring to the [Zymphonies](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal8_zymphonies_theme) theme. When I check [Twig Template naming conventions](https://www.drupal.org/node/2354645) I could see there are naming conventions for Twig templates. But what is the difference in giving Twig plain twig templates inside the templates folder and by giving specific twig templates in specific folders inside templates folder?

[image: screen]

Comment: I added the following sentence to https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/drupal-8-theme-folder-structure#templates: `You also can organize your templates in subfolders, for example all block templates inside templates/block and all views templates inside templates/views.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These folders are arbitrary. As long as the template is in the `[THEME ROOT]/templates` folder, it will be picked up. Using folders is simply the developer being well organized.

Comment: Meaning that we can give twig templates inside in any folder and Drupal will pick that?

Comment: No it has to be in the templates folder or a sub folder.

Answer (score 1):

by default the `[MY_THEME]/templates` folder holding `twig` files is flattened, have a look at this folder `/core/modules/system/templates`. So, it's seen as a good practice to bring such organization to this folder and it's up to you to determine what logic suits your case. The `twig` engine is smart enough to pick up the right `twig` file.

Just to draw your attention when it comes to override an existing template, let say you want to override the default `search form` which uses this `twig` template `/templates/forms/form.html.twig` then you `should` create the template following this path `/templates/forms/form--search-form.html.twig` just to keep certain logic, but this doesn't prevent you to locate that file in an other folder or simply under `/templates`

you can also tell Drupal 8 where to find your new template using `MY_THEME_theme` hook :

```
function MY_THEME_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'search_form' => [
      'render element' => 'form',
      'template' => 'form/form--search-form',
    ],
  ];
}
```

don't forget to clear and rebuild cache to force twig engine to take in consideration your new `twig` file.